# directory owner permission does not get updated properly via ansible loop

Tags: ansible, file-permissions, ansible-playbook

I am trying to create and update directory permission on my linux machine by using below ansible task but it does not change the ownership properly:

for instance: directory `/home/xyz/xyz/{{ IDM }}` and `/home/{{ IDM }}` ownership permssion gets reverted to `{{ IDM }}:{{ IDM }}`

```yaml
- name: create directory with loop
  file:
    path: "{{ item.dest }}"
    mode: "{{item.mode}}"
    owner: "{{ IDM }}"
    group: "{{ IDM }}"
    recurse: yes
    state: directory
  loop:
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}', mode: '0755', owner: root, group: root }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/.ssh', mode: '0700', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/to_xyz', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/to_xyz/known_customers', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/from_xyz', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/from_xyz/merchant_invoice', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/from_xyz/clearing', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/from_xyz/settlement_report', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/archive', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/archive/settlement_report', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/archive/clearing', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/{{ IDM }}/archive/dunning', mode: '0777', owner: "{{ IDM }}", group: "{{ IDM }}" }
  - { dest: '/home/xyz/xyz/{{ IDM }}', mode: '0755', owner: 'root', group: 'root' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because you define it as `{{ IDM }}`. Set `owner` and `group` to `{{ item.owner }}` and `{{ item.group }}` instead.

```yaml
- name: create directory with loop
  file:
    path: "{{ item.dest }}"
    mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
    owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
    group: "{{ item.group }}"
    recurse: yes
    state: directory
```